# QSSTV/Hamlib and RTL-SDR/HackRF One

Tags: rtl-sdr, linux, sstv

I came across [QSSTV](http://users.telenet.be/on4qz/index.html) today. It's a relatively new Linux program for SSTV and DRM.

The config suggests that it can use a number of different external radios as transmitters. What I'd really like to try (as mentioned in this post: [Video transmission between ATV and SSTV](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5179)), is send images from a HackRF One, initially, to a nearby RTL-SDR dongle.

However, neither the Hack RF One, or RTL-SDR are listed in the radio setup page (which appears to use **Hamlib** as a source).

Has anyone had success with the above, either with QSSTV, Hamlib (maybe with a different program), or even with GNU Radio Companion?

Indeed, is there much in the way of SDR SSTV/DRM experimentation?

Answer (score 2):

The signal interface with traditional hardware radios (such as those controlled by hamlib) is through an audio device (sound card). A glance at QSSTV's manual looks like it works that way.

SDR programs generally output the demodulated audio *to* an audio device.

Therefore, what you need is a loopback audio device, one which is used as an output by your main program (e.g. gqrx) and an input by QSSTV. I believe that most Linux audio systems have the capability to create such devices, but I'm not familiar with the specifics.

You can also just use an audio cable from a line-out to a line-in (not necessarily on the same computer), of course, if that's more convenient.

Comment: For linux you probably want http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/FAQ/#index39h3